# Fixing magento email form in contacts page

Tags: magento-1.8, email, email-templates

When I receive an email in my inbox, the from field is always the same. It looks like that's because it uses the senders name from the general contact email.

I'd prefer this to be the name field value. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you'll probably have to override the method `postAction` in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/indexControllers.php`.

**/!\ Don't modify this file directly but create a custom module to override it /!\**

This is the part you should modify:

```
 $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
 /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
 $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
     ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
     ->sendTransactional(
     Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
     trim($post['email'],                                   // put the email you've got through the form
     // Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),  // instead of the general contact email from the config
     Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
     null,
     array('data' => $postObject)
 );
```